# Collect prices from page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a bookmarklet now and faced this task: I need to collect all prices from any page.

The problem is that the price may be in multiple formats ($19.00, 15.45$, etc), not counting different currencies and html markup. The good news is that I'm using jquery.

If anybody has an idea how it can be accomplish, please share :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: we COULD have a brilliant idea my friend, but no markup no solution ;-)

Comment: You need to write a price extraction routine that is capable of dealing with all the possible formats. There's no magic bullet in general for dealing with data quality issues.  If you can specify some constraints there might be some tricks to suggest.

Comment: "Any page" you mean your own pages (same domain) or external pages as well?

Comment: http://www.swegler.com/becky/blog/2009/12/16/regular-expression-for-dollar-amount-validation/

Comment: EvilP, Shadow Wizard, there's no specific page, it's a bookmarklet for extracting data from any page. So, there's no markup for an example.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no consistent markup you're probably going to have to write some regex's for the known patterns.  For example:

To capture a pattern like $19.00 you'll use a regex that looks something like this:

```
\$[0-9]*.?[0-9]{1,2}
```

Since you're target data is so unstructured i'm not sure there is a single good answer to this.  You'll need to identify the patterns you are looking for and write the regex's to identify them.

Test your regular expressions here: http://regexpal.com/

Best of luck.

-R